# Bootstrap columns. Blank space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I'm posting news, I got this blank space between posts and I don't know who causes this. Is there something missing in this code ? This occurs in every categories page also

[image]

This is my code:

```
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">

      @if(count($latest))
      <div class="col-md-12">
      <a href="/post/{{$latest->slug}}/{{$latest->id}}">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{!! url($latest->image) !!}" alt="" style="padding: 0px; height: 400px; width: 720px"></a>
        <h2 style="margin-top: 0; color: #666;">

          @foreach($latest->category as $cat)
            <a style="color: red; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none" href="/categories/{{$cat->name}}">{{$cat->name}}</a>
          @endforeach

        <br><a class="post" href="/post/{{$latest->slug}}/{{$latest->id}}">{!! strip_tags(link_to_action('PostsController@show', $latest->title, [$latest->slug, $latest->id])) !!}</a></h2>
        <span style="color: #b8b8b8">Paskeblta {{$latest->created_at}}</span>
        <hr>
      </div>
      @else
       <p>Nėra naujienų</p>
      @endif



      <div class="row">
            @foreach($posts as $post)
            @unless ($post->id == $latest->id)
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
        <a href="/post/{{$post->slug}}/{{$post->id}}">
        <img class="img-responsive" style="width: 352px; height: 180px" src="{!! url($post->image) !!}" alt=""></a>
          <h3 class="post" style="font-size: 1.4em;">

          @foreach($post->category as $cat)
          <a style="color: red; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none" href="/categories/{{$cat->name}}">{{$cat->name}}</a>
          @endforeach

          <br><a class="post" href="/post/{{$post->slug}}/{{$post->id}}">{{strip_tags($post->title)}}</a></h3>
          <span style="color: #b8b8b8">Paskelbta {{$post->created_at}}</span>
          <br><br>
        </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
        @endunless
        @endforeach
      </div><!--/row-->
       {!! $posts->render() !!}
    </div><!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->
```

Comment: please create JSFIDDLE of the html that is having problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its happening because of the child div inside the 2nd div (row) are floating element with dynamic height. If you've noticed, first post's excerpt's length is longer then the others, which is why it's height is also more then the others.

You can solve your problem by applying below css. You need to put an extra class name for this --

```
  <div class="row recent-posts">
        @foreach($posts as $post)
       ....
       ....
    @endunless
    @endforeach
  </div><!--/row-->


.row.recent-posts div:nth-child(2n+1){
    clear:both;
}
```

OR

You can also avoid this issue by using a fixed

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">

.col-xs-6, .col-lg-6{
     height:400px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The height fixed the problem !

Comment: There was a typo mistake on 1st solution. I fixed it. You can use the first solution as well..

Answer (score 0):

Probably 3th post is widther than 50% of your contener.

```
<img class="img-responsive" style="width: 352px; height: 180px" src="{!! url($post->image) !!}" alt=""></a>
```

Try remove width from style.